# UDF to return formatted number

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions, udf

Sometimes I like to display numbers along with text in the same cell. To do this, I custom format the cell to something like 0.00" test", e.g. a cell `A1` with formula `=PI()`, but formatted with custom format `0.00" test"` would return a displayed result of `3.14 test`.

Crucially, the value of the cell is unchanged by the formatting - you can still do `=A1 * 3` in another cell and get the result - since the *value* of `A1` is still Pi, only it's display has changed.

**For a UDF** that returns a numerical value (in my case, `Long`, but it could be any number), is there a way of returning a cell such that it is displayed 1 way, but it's actual value (`.Value2` in VBA I believe) is a number, not text.

I've tried `Format(` in VBA, but it returns a text string. I would just format my cell how I want it manually, but as you can see from the below code, the formatting is dependent on intermediate results (I'm trying to return the value formatted with the time the calculation took).

```
UDF_RESULT = Format(valueResult.Length, IIf(tElapsed < timeout, "0" & " """ & Round(tElapsed, 2) & "s""", "0"))
```

This would be easy to do with a Macro, but within a UDF it's harder. I could declare all of the intermediate values at a module level, then a `Worksheet_Calculate()` macro can access those values and apply the custom formatting, but a UDF-wrapped approach would be much better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

You're confusing a cell's *value* with its *number format*. A UDF can compute a *value*, and the cell is free to format that value as needed.

So if a UDF returns a number, the cell's value is the result of that function - a number.

Just format the cell as needed. A function doesn't format anything.

Comment: Of course I would, but the formatting is dependant on an intermediate result, so it's a pain to do from outside the UDF. I was toying with using `Application.Caller` to try and cheat the system, it's proving relatively fruitless. Are there any loopholes of that sort? How does Excel know to stop that line of code from executing and can I turn off that awareness? Would there be repercussions?

Comment: Excel doesn't stop anything from executing; however it knows it's in the middle of calculating a worksheet, and if a cell invokes a UDF then it knows what the execution context is, and if it's hard-wired to throw an error when such or such method is invoked in the context of a UDF computation, then there's not much you can do about it. If what you need is a macro, why not write a macro?

Comment: You can change format from within a general macro, just not from a function  that's been called from a cell value. You could have your function set some sort of global variable that is inspected by a sub that's run after-the-fact, so the sub could do the formatting for you. Maybe even hooked to the worksheet_change event?